# CSS 3D containers like shown in post

Tags: html, css, 3d

I've been trying to get this container box into my webpage with html and css.
but I can't seem to get it working properly, could anyone help me out with it?

I dont have any code at the moment, since I've only been copy and pasting tutorials and trying to figure out how it works, but I cant seem to get it right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

**Update with shadow**

```css
:root{background: #c7c7c7; padding: 80px;}
div{
    background: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: 480px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto
}

div:before, div:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #f2f2f2
}
div:before{
    left: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    top: 20px;
    transform: skew(0deg,45deg);
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 0px #9D9C9C, 0 2px 2px #f2f2f2;
}
div:after{
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    left: 20px;
    transform: skew(45deg,0deg);
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 1px 0px #9D9C9C, 8px 0 16px #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<div><div/>
```

**Update without shadow**

```css
:root{background: #c7c7c7; padding: 80px;}
div{
    background: white;
    width: 280px;
    height: 480px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto
}

div:before, div:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #f2f2f2
}
div:before{
    left: 100%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    top: 20px;
    transform: skew(0deg,45deg);
}
div:after{
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    left: 20px;
    transform: skew(45deg,0deg);
}
```

```html
<div><div/>
```

**Old Update**

```css
:root{background-color: #c7c7c7; height: 100vh}
main{
  width: calc(100vw - 100px);
  height: 120vh;
  margin: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: relative
}
main:before, main:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
}

main:before{
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: 50px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  right: -50px;
  top: 40px
}
main:after{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Or Shadow

```css
:root{background-color: #c7c7c7; height: 100vh}
main{
    width: calc(100vw - 100px);
    height: 120vh;
    margin: 20px;
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 50px 0 #f2f2f2;
}
main:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 50px solid #c7c7c7;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    right: -50px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get like the the same border on the bottom